# Flutter model for FireBase - add a List of objects

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I try to create a collection of courses that contains a sub-collection of lessons,
when I add a single lesson,
it works,
but I don't know how to add a list of object lessons !??

```
class Lesson{
  String LessonName;
  int LessonChapter;
  
  Lesson({required this.LessonName,required this.LessonChapter});

  Map<String, Object?> toMap() {
    return {
      'LessonName': LessonName,
      'LessonChapter': LessonChapter,  
    };
  }
}

class Course{
  String CourseName;
  List<Lesson> Lessons;

  Course({required this.CourseName, required this.Lesson});

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'CourseName': CourseName,
      'Lessons': Lessons.first.toMap(),  <---- here
    };
  }
}
```

```
List<Lesson> Lessons=[{'Lesson1','3'},{'Lesson2','4'}] ;

FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Courses')
   .add(Course(
            CourseName: CourseName,
            Lessons: Lessons   <---- here
        ).toMap()
);
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Did you try `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Courses').add(Lessons)`?

Comment: I want to add in firebase a course with a list of Lessons and not only one lesson as I did here 'Lessons': Lessons.first.toMap(),   but I don't know how do it

Comment: Did you try `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Courses').add(Lessons)`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
List<Map<String, String>> data = lessons.map((e) => e.toMap()).toList();
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Courses').add({'key': data});
```

Comment: does not this help you?

Comment: no, I try to add a sub-collection of lesson objects to my collection courses, (this is just a simple example that I share here as a question)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by editing this section:

**Here is code snippet:**

```
Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
List lessonsMap = [] ;
lessons.forEach((element) {lessonsMap.add(element.toMap()) ;});

return {
  'CourseName': CourseName,
  'lessons': lessonsMap
};
}
```